# Perl : Extract domain name

Tags: regex, perl, url

## Extract the domaine name of an URL

Yet another request to parse an URL, but I have found many incomplete or theoretical examples.  I would like to have something that work in perl for sure.

I have the following URLs:

```
https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html
http://linksyssmartwifi.com/ui/1.0.1.1001/dynamic/login.html
http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl1line.txt
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5jNDUmF2eUJuSnM
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html
http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl1line.txt
https://feedly.com/i/my
http://vimhelp.appspot.com/
https://git-scm.com/doc
https://read.amazon.com/
https://github.com/netsamir/following
https://scotch.io/
https://servicios.dgi.gub.uy/
https://sourcemaking.com/
https://stackedit.io/editor
https://stripe.com/be
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/
https://training.github.com/
https://vimeo.com/54505525
https://vimeo.com/tag:drew+neil
https://web.whatsapp.com/
https://www.ctan.org/
https://www.eff.org/
https://www.mybeluga.com/
https://www.solveforx.com/
https://www.symynd.com/
https://www.symynd.com/#
https://www.tizen.org/
http://workforall.net/CDS-Credit-default-Swaps.html#Credit_Default_Swaps_CDS
```

Try to extract the domain name only. For instance:

```
linksyssmartwifi.com
amazon.com
github.com
```

I have tried with Perl and Vim but could not accomplish the task.  My best 
approximation is the following

```
 perl -pe 's!(^https?\://.*[\.](.+\..+?)/.*$)!$1 -- [$2] !g' all_urls_sorted.txt
```

Some of them are correctly parsed (see in []), other not :

```
   https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid -- [google.com] 
https://sourcemaking.com/
https://stackedit.io/editor
https://stripe.com/be
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ -- [heroku.com] 
https://training.github.com/ -- [github.com] 
https://vimeo.com/54505525
https://vimeo.com/tag:drew+neil
https://web.whatsapp.com/ -- [whatsapp.com] 
https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC -- [haskell.org]
```

As my tests showed, the URL that start straight from // (in https?://) are being excluded.

If you know how to solve this problem I would be very happy.

Thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use URI;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $uri = URI->new($_);
    my $host = $uri->host;
    my ($domain) = $host =~ m/([^.]+\.[^.]+$)/;
    say $domain;
}

__DATA__
https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html
http://linksyssmartwifi.com/ui/1.0.1.1001/dynamic/login.html
http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl1line.txt
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5jNDUmF2eUJuSnM
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html
http://www.catonmat.net/download/perl1line.txt
https://feedly.com/i/my
http://vimhelp.appspot.com/
https://git-scm.com/doc
https://read.amazon.com/
https://github.com/netsamir/following
https://scotch.io/
https://servicios.dgi.gub.uy/
https://sourcemaking.com/
https://stackedit.io/editor
https://stripe.com/be
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/
https://training.github.com/
https://vimeo.com/54505525
https://vimeo.com/tag:drew+neil
https://web.whatsapp.com/
https://www.ctan.org/
https://www.eff.org/
https://www.mybeluga.com/
https://www.solveforx.com/
https://www.symynd.com/
https://www.symynd.com/#
https://www.tizen.org/
http://workforall.net/CDS-Credit-default-Swaps.html#Credit_Default_Swaps_CDS
```

Outputs:

```
sourceforge.net
linksyssmartwifi.com
catonmat.net
github.com
google.com
gnu.org
catonmat.net
feedly.com
appspot.com
git-scm.com
amazon.com
github.com
scotch.io
gub.uy
sourcemaking.com
stackedit.io
stripe.com
heroku.com
github.com
vimeo.com
vimeo.com
whatsapp.com
ctan.org
eff.org
mybeluga.com
solveforx.com
symynd.com
symynd.com
tizen.org
workforall.net
```

Comment: What about `www.bbc.co.uk`?

Comment: That's what `Domain::PublicSuffix` tries to do.

Answer (score 3):

My best approximation is [URI::URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::URL):

```
foreach my $uri (@filecontents) {
    my $uriobj = URL::URL->new($uri);
    my $host = $uriobj -> host;
    my @parts = split /\./, $host;
    print "$uri -- $parts[-2]$parts[-1]\n";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: URI::URL is provided for backwards compatibility. For new code, use [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) instead.

Answer (score 2):

A regex solution is:

```
//(?:[^./]+[.])*([^/.]+[.][^/.]+)/
```

If the trailing slash is optional, just add a `?`:

```
//(?:[^./]+[.])*([^/.]+[.][^/.]+)/?
```

This should be used with the global modifier and a delimiter other than `/`.

Essentially, it's looking between the `//` and the next `/`.

If there are any extra sub-domains, they will be caught by the `(?:[^./]+[.])*`. The main domain will fall into the capture group `([^/.]+[.][^/.]+)`.

Comment: What if there is no / after the host name?

Comment: I have tested this solution and it works and it is line because it is pure one-liners perl with regex.  Without / after the hostname it fails. The (?:[^./]+[.])* make the difference with my own solution. Thank you.

Comment: @SamirSadek It's pretty simple to adjust for an optional trailing slash, just add `?` (see edit.)